# WebBrowser.Navigate(...) throws COMException

Tags: exception, internet-explorer, browser, comexception

I'm developing an Internet Explorer command button that will open a specific web page once clicked. Here's a snippet of code (`IEApp` is a reference to an instance of `IE.WebBrowser`):

```
IEApp.Navigate(sURL, ref one, ref two, ref three, ref four);
```

The above line throws the following COMException:

```
Exception Source:      Interop.SHDocVw
Exception Type:        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception Message:     The requested resource is in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700AA)
Exception Target Site: Navigate
```

This wasn't a problem on IE6 or IE7. Any ideas on what's going wrong? I'm using AddInExpress for creating the command button.

Cheers!
Christian

Comment: Can you run your app with Fiddler? This thread (http://forums.iis.net/t/1146952.aspx) suggests that the problem might not be on the client side and you might be getting an HTTP 500 back from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no activity to be seen in Fiddler. But the error message is almost instant.

Also, I'm curious as to what "The requested resource is in use" implies. I can see that the busy-property if true, but the browser is really doing nothing.

Comment: It could be the issue mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20612526/238419)

Answer (score 5):

That's ERROR_BUSY usually happens when IE is doing something else, e.g. displaying a window.alert message box.
Try suppress script errors and Implement IDocHostShowUI and return S_OK without blocking the message pump

Comment: The current URL is about:blank, also when checking the property on the IE.WebBrowser so I don't think it's actually doing anything.

Comment: what is the return value of IWebBrowser2::get_ReadyState

Comment: try stop the current navigation (if you indeed want to stop when the page is not completed loaded) or add the navigation to a request queue and use a timer to wait IWebBrowser2::get_Busy returns false.

Comment: Adding an IEApp.Stop(); before the Nagivate, doesn't change the outcome, I'm afraid.

Comment: what is the value of IWebBrowser2::get_Busy?

Comment: It says 'true', even right after I do a .Stop();

This is the code:

string sURL;
System.Object one = null;
System.Object two = null;
System.Object three = null;
System.Object four = null;
sURL = "http://www.google.dk";
IEApp.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(IEApp.Busy.ToString());
IEApp.Navigate(sURL, ref one, ref two, ref three, ref four);

Comment: where is this code in? if it is button click then disable the button when the busy property is true.

Answer (score 1):

could this help: turning off UAC in Windows, if you are using a server kind version:

screen-shoots here: http://blog.vincentbrouillet.com/post/2011/02/10/watin%3A-The-requested-resource-is-in-use

I had this error, and it was quite random. I tried killing IE before running the tests. It kind of work, but not all the time.

Comment: Nah, can't ask clients to disable UAC. See my solution below.

Comment: @ChrispedDK : I am also looking for solution for this problem