# Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am developing a windows application with a WebBrowser control that navigates to a sharepoint site.
My problem is that i am getting JavaScript error.

How can i disable the JavaScript error? I don't want them to pop up.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: For the record, under the hood this property does this.AxIWebBrowser2.Silent = true;

Comment: Should also have added that this.AxIWebBrowser2.Silent = true suppresses all pop-ups, not just script errors, hence the WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressd appears to be improperly named.

Comment: Can anyone tell me,where i should write this line in code? Help Please!!

Comment: this will remove all popup including login boxes. Best is to use what  redclax has done

Comment: @Hardevgun You can just set the property on the control itself (at design time) unless you have some occasion where you want to change it.

Answer (score 53):

This disables the script errors and also disables other windows.. such as the NTLM login window or the client certificate accept window.  The below will suppress only javascript errors.

```
// Hides script errors without hiding other dialog boxes.
private void SuppressScriptErrorsOnly(WebBrowser browser)
{
    // Ensure that ScriptErrorsSuppressed is set to false.
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;

    // Handle DocumentCompleted to gain access to the Document object.
    browser.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
            browser_DocumentCompleted);
}

private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.Window.Error += 
        new HtmlElementErrorEventHandler(Window_Error);
}

private void Window_Error(object sender, 
    HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore the error and suppress the error dialog box. 
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This should have more upvotes, definitely the right way to do it. Bonus for being able to log errors or show your own notification instead of never knowing they ever happened (i.e. for kiosk application).

Comment: In my testing I found that there are script error dialogs appearing before the DocumentCompleted event is fired.  However if the WebBrowser.Document.Window.Error handler is attached as a response to the Navigated and FileDownloaded events, then most if not all script error dialogs can be suppressed. (FileDownloaded handles most scenarios, except, for example WebBrowser.GoBack, which is handled by Navigated.  Navigated alone would miss a page being refreshed.)

Comment: @Ej. Nice, I have had problems where not all JavaScript errors get caught and this would probably fix the problem, would you by chance have an example of how you implemented it.?

Comment: This is what I have used:
http://pastebin.com/UThKifw8
Although, we also had to get the user to upgrade to IE8 before the dialogs completely went away.

Comment: FYI I couldn't use this solution because the HTML pages contained framesets and frames and this caused the cross frame security checks to throw an exception (see [WebBrowser.Document property getter throws UnauthorizedAccessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994402/webbrowser-document-property-getter-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception))

Answer (score 14):

None of the above solutions were suitable for my scenario, handling .Navigated and .FileDownload events seemed like a good fit but accessing the WebBrowser.Document property threw an UnauthorizedAccessException which is caused by cross frame scripting security (our web content contains frames - all on the same domain/address but frames have their own security holes that are being blocked).

The solution that worked was to override IOleCommandTarget and to catch the script error commands at that level. Here's the WebBrowser sub-class to achieve this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Subclassed WebBrowser that suppresses error pop-ups.
/// 
/// Notes.
/// ScriptErrorsSuppressed property is not used because this actually suppresses *all* pop-ups.
/// 
/// More info at:
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control
/// </summary>
public class WebBrowserEx : WebBrowser
{
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// Initialise browser control and attach customer event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    public WebBrowserEx()
    {
        this.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overrides

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to allow custom script error handling.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
        return new WebBrowserSiteEx(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Inner Class [WebBrowserSiteEx]

    /// <summary>
    /// Sub-class to allow custom script error handling.
    /// </summary>
    protected class WebBrowserSiteEx : WebBrowserSite, NativeMethods.IOleCommandTarget
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public WebBrowserSiteEx(WebBrowserEx webBrowser) : base (webBrowser)
        {   
        }

        /// <summary>Queries the object for the status of one or more commands generated by user interface events.</summary>
        /// <param name="pguidCmdGroup">The GUID of the command group.</param>
        /// <param name="cCmds">The number of commands in <paramref name="prgCmds" />.</param>
        /// <param name="prgCmds">An array of OLECMD structures that indicate the commands for which the caller needs status information. This method fills the <paramref name="cmdf" /> member of each structure with values taken from the OLECMDF enumeration.</param>
        /// <param name="pCmdText">An OLECMDTEXT structure in which to return name and/or status information of a single command. This parameter can be null to indicate that the caller does not need this information.</param>
        /// <returns>This method returns S_OK on success. Other possible return values include the following.
        /// E_FAIL The operation failed.
        /// E_UNEXPECTED An unexpected error has occurred.
        /// E_POINTER The <paramref name="prgCmds" /> argument is null.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP The <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" /> parameter is not null but does not specify a recognized command group.</returns>
        public int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, int cCmds, NativeMethods.OLECMD prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
        {
            if((int)NativeMethods.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR == prgCmds.cmdID)
            {   // Do nothing (suppress script errors)
                return NativeMethods.S_OK;
            }

            // Indicate that command is unknown. The command will then be handled by another IOleCommandTarget.
            return NativeMethods.OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP;
        }

        /// <summary>Executes the specified command.</summary>
        /// <param name="pguidCmdGroup">The GUID of the command group.</param>
        /// <param name="nCmdID">The command ID.</param>
        /// <param name="nCmdexecopt">Specifies how the object should execute the command. Possible values are taken from the <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDEXECOPT" /> and <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDID_WINDOWSTATE_FLAG" /> enumerations.</param>
        /// <param name="pvaIn">The input arguments of the command.</param>
        /// <param name="pvaOut">The output arguments of the command.</param>
        /// <returns>This method returns S_OK on success. Other possible return values include 
        /// OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP The <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" /> parameter is not null but does not specify a recognized command group.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_NOTSUPPORTED The <paramref name="nCmdID" /> parameter is not a valid command in the group identified by <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" />.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_DISABLED The command identified by <paramref name="nCmdID" /> is currently disabled and cannot be executed.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_NOHELP The caller has asked for help on the command identified by <paramref name="nCmdID" />, but no help is available.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_CANCELED The user canceled the execution of the command.</returns>
        public int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, int nCmdID, int nCmdexecopt, object[] pvaIn, int pvaOut)
        {
            if((int)NativeMethods.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR == nCmdID)
            {   // Do nothing (suppress script errors)
                return NativeMethods.S_OK;
            }

            // Indicate that command is unknown. The command will then be handled by another IOleCommandTarget.
            return NativeMethods.OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

~

```
/// <summary>
/// Native (unmanaged) methods, required for custom command handling for the WebBrowser control.
/// </summary>
public static class NativeMethods
{
    /// From docobj.h
    public const int OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP = -2147221244;

    /// <summary>
    /// From Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop (Visual Studio 2010 SDK).
    /// </summary>
    public enum OLECMDID
    {
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_OPEN = 1,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_NEW,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SAVE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SAVEAS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SAVECOPYAS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PRINT,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PAGESETUP,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SPELL,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PROPERTIES,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_CUT,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_COPY,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PASTE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PASTESPECIAL,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_UNDO,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_REDO,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SELECTALL,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_CLEARSELECTION,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_ZOOM,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_GETZOOMRANGE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_UPDATECOMMANDS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_REFRESH,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_STOP,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_HIDETOOLBARS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETPROGRESSMAX,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETPROGRESSPOS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETPROGRESSTEXT,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETTITLE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETDOWNLOADSTATE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_STOPDOWNLOAD,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_ONTOOLBARACTIVATED,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_FIND,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_DELETE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_HTTPEQUIV,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_HTTPEQUIV_DONE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_ENABLE_INTERACTION,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_ONUNLOAD,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PROPERTYBAG2,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PREREFRESH,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SHOWMESSAGE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SHOWFIND,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SHOWPAGESETUP,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SHOWPRINT,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_CLOSE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_ALLOWUILESSSAVEAS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_DONTDOWNLOADCSS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_UPDATEPAGESTATUS,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PRINT2,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW2,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_SETPRINTTEMPLATE,
        /// <summary />
        OLECMDID_GETPRINTTEMPLATE
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// From Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell (Visual Studio 2010 SDK).
    /// </summary>
    public const int S_OK = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// OLE command structure.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class OLECMD
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Command ID.
        /// </summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cmdID;
        /// <summary>
        /// Flags associated with cmdID.
        /// </summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cmdf;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables the dispatching of commands between objects and containers.
    /// </summary>
    [ComVisible(true), Guid("B722BCCB-4E68-101B-A2BC-00AA00404770"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComImport]
    public interface IOleCommandTarget
    {
        /// <summary>Queries the object for the status of one or more commands generated by user interface events.</summary>
        /// <param name="pguidCmdGroup">The GUID of the command group.</param>
        /// <param name="cCmds">The number of commands in <paramref name="prgCmds" />.</param>
        /// <param name="prgCmds">An array of <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMD" /> structures that indicate the commands for which the caller needs status information.</param>
        /// <param name="pCmdText">An <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT" /> structure in which to return name and/or status information of a single command. This parameter can be null to indicate that the caller does not need this information.</param>
        /// <returns>This method returns S_OK on success. Other possible return values include the following.
        /// E_FAIL The operation failed.
        /// E_UNEXPECTED An unexpected error has occurred.
        /// E_POINTER The <paramref name="prgCmds" /> argument is null.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUPThe <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" /> parameter is not null but does not specify a recognized command group.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, int cCmds, [In] [Out] NativeMethods.OLECMD prgCmds, [In] [Out] IntPtr pCmdText);

        /// <summary>Executes the specified command.</summary>
        /// <param name="pguidCmdGroup">The GUID of the command group.</param>
        /// <param name="nCmdID">The command ID.</param>
        /// <param name="nCmdexecopt">Specifies how the object should execute the command. Possible values are taken from the <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDEXECOPT" /> and <see cref="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDID_WINDOWSTATE_FLAG" /> enumerations.</param>
        /// <param name="pvaIn">The input arguments of the command.</param>
        /// <param name="pvaOut">The output arguments of the command.</param>
        /// <returns>This method returns S_OK on success. Other possible return values include 
        /// OLECMDERR_E_UNKNOWNGROUP The <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" /> parameter is not null but does not specify a recognized command group.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_NOTSUPPORTED The <paramref name="nCmdID" /> parameter is not a valid command in the group identified by <paramref name="pguidCmdGroup" />.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_DISABLED The command identified by <paramref name="nCmdID" /> is currently disabled and cannot be executed.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_NOHELP The caller has asked for help on the command identified by <paramref name="nCmdID" />, but no help is available.
        /// OLECMDERR_E_CANCELED The user canceled the execution of the command.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, int nCmdID, int nCmdexecopt, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [In] object[] pvaIn, int pvaOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Then only working solution at this moment. Many thanks :D.

Comment: Until the next version of IE!!

Comment: I see. And which IE versions this method supports?

Comment: I was working with IE10 and 11, but my main concern would be what is happening with the IE replacement - Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Nothing is going to happen with Microsoft Edge because Microsoft is not going to let you embed Edge in a WinForms app in an attempt to force you to build an app for their new locked-down "Universal" platform instead - (search for `embed` on this page - https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/apps-engine/ )

Comment: I was looking for this.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  It only suppresses error popups, not all popups like ScriptErrorsSuppressed does, and handling .Navigated and .FileDownload events didn't work for me.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: Excellent work! I this gives me a whole lot to learn from. Thank you for posting it!

Answer (score 2):

axwebbrowser1.Silent = true;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
class extendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor which will make the browser to ignore all errors
    /// </summary>
    public extendedWebBrowser()
    {
        this.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        FieldInfo field = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (field != null)
        {
             object axIWebBrowser2 = field.GetValue(this);
             axIWebBrowser2.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, axIWebBrowser2, new object[] { true });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this :

```
 private static bool TrySetSuppressScriptErrors(WebBrowser webBrowser, bool value)
    {
        FieldInfo field = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (field != null)
        {
            object axIWebBrowser2 = field.GetValue(webBrowser);
            if (axIWebBrowser2 != null)
            {
                axIWebBrowser2.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, axIWebBrowser2, new object[] { value });
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

usage example to set webBrowser to silent : TrySetSuppressScriptErrors(webBrowser,true)

Answer (score 0):

Previous solutions didn't work for me. on .net 4.5 / Win10 so edited it slightly to make it work. Thank you **Allan** and **Adil** your code helped me a lot.

```
//Example: UIHelper.TrySetSuppressScriptErrors(webBrowserControl1, true)


public static class UIHelper
{
    public static bool TrySetSuppressScriptErrors(WebBrowser webBrowser, bool value)
    {
        try
        {
            FieldInfo field = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //this worked
            if (field == null)
                field = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            if (field != null)
            {
                object axIWebBrowser2 = field.GetValue(webBrowser);
                if (axIWebBrowser2 != null)
                {
                    axIWebBrowser2.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, axIWebBrowser2, new object[] { value });
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```