# C# WebBrowser - how to get rid of JavaScript error prompt?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser

I'm working with C# WebBrowser, and sometimes when the page is loaded (not always) I get following prompt:

```
An error has occured in the script on this page.
Line 1
Char 45774
Error Object required
Code 0
URL http://xxx.i_replaced_the_link_here.com/blah_BLAH_blah123

Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
Yes / No
```

I want to continue, but I cannot be constantly clicking the Yes button.

How do you think I can fix it?

Comment: You need to fix your javascript do that it doesn't raise errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control)

Comment: where does your question related to C# tag ?. Its just an option for Web browser settings related to Javascript.

Answer (score 17):

You can set the `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed` control property to `true`. You wont be getting any errors that way.