# Visual C# - Getting rid of "Script Error" when using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

Ok so I have a WebBrowser called **wb**. And I load a page into wb using `wb.Navigate("url");` When the page loads I get a box saying "Script Error".

Here is the one I get
[image: The Error I get]

How can I keep this from popping up in my program?

Comment: Search for your solution instead of asking new questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure on newer browser control, but off the top of my head, there is an option called SuppressScriptErrors or something like that. Set that to true in your code before performing work. You'll also have to make sure that under Internet Options that debugging web pages is off (if you're getting the dialog above, it is off).

http://www.dev102.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-suppress-disable-script-errors.html

```
wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method ScriptErrorsSuppressed referenced above is not supported in the webBrowser control in .Net 6 and higher.

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

we need to build a handler and override the default script error window.