# Browser Scripts in VB.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, browser, error-handling, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows form application with a browser in it. The browser opens to a secure website that will call a POPUP window asking for the Username and Password. Once logged in the site throws a bunch of Javascript Error Messages. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent these messages or at least automatically choose YES KEEP RUNNING SCRIPTS for the user so it is transparent.

In the Control Properties I set SUPPRESS ERRORS to TRUE but then the website does not prompt for the USERNAME and PASSWORD  it just says YOU DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO VIEW THIS PAGE. So setting the SUPPRESSION to TRUE will not work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Oh, also, I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010.

Comment: Will this probably solve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7841596/752527

Comment: It looks like it would work but it is for C. I don't think it will trqanslate the same and I'm not sure exactly how to translate it.

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to either rework the protocols used in the link?

or perhaps DISABLE JAVASCRIPT ERRORS only?

Comment: Did not that code work for you? There are online c# to vb.net converters online.