# Disable JavaScript error in WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, wpf-controls

I am developing a windows application with a **WPF WebBrowser** control that navigates to a JavaScript related site.
My problem is that i am getting JavaScript error.

How can i disable the JavaScript error? I don't want them to pop up.

I find answer for WinForms WebBrowser at [Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476360/disable-javascript-error-in-webbrowser-control). But "ScriptErrorsSuppressed" property doesn't exist in WPF WebBrowser.
How to do this in WPF WebBrowser.

Thanks
Satish

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18289217/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found easy way. So i just change WPF WebBrowser to WinForms WebBrowser and webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
Thanks
Satish

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//add the handler.  
...  
myWebBrowser.Document.Window.Error += new HtmlElementErrorEventHandler(this.JavascriptErrorHandler);  
...  

private void JavascriptErrorHandler(object sender, HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e)  
{  
    // Handle the error. For now, just ignore.  
    e.Handled = true;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @hicurin ... i mention the WebBrowser from WPF (System.windows.controls).Your answer related to  WinForms related Web Browser.