# c# internet explorer control , make style none as if wpf window style none and allowtransparency

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer

I wonder, is there a way to make internet explorer style none window like wpf application.

Thanks,

**Code :**

```
public static void test()
        {

            System.Type oType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application");

            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = Activator.CreateInstance(oType) as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer;

            ie.MenuBar = false;
            ie.ToolBar = 0;
            ie.StatusBar = false;
            ie.AddressBar = false;

            ie.Width = 800;
            ie.Height = 600;

            ie.Visible = true;
            ie.Navigate("http://m.naver.com");

        }
```

Comment: What did you try? The code you are showing is not trying to set any style.

Comment: i want to remove internet explorer frame such as border, captions. it's like none style window in wpf application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to achieve that with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, however you could use [System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Window window = new Window();
window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
window.Width = 800;
window.Height = 600;

WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Navigate("http://m.naver.com");

window.Content = webBrowser;
window.Show();
```

And remember to Dispose your WebBrowser object after you are done with it if you don't want a memory leak.

Comment: thanks for reply. if i use webbrowser, some errors occur due to javascript files from original website such as "m.naver.com" or any site using javascript. so i need to find other solutions.

Comment: If this is the only problem, you can [supress](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194230/1378699) or [fix](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72ffeddd-5d02-491b-8b7b-6740befc46a0/webbrowser-error-when-using-external-javascript?forum=wpf) the JavaScript errors.

Comment: oh..Thanks for your kind explanation. I'd never been realized to use supress method without you. Thanks!! I hope you someday get more benefits from  others because you did good works.