# WebBrowser control in WinForm using C# not playing video

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing HTML from a WinForm to a WebBrowser control.  I initialize the control by navigating to `about:blank`.  The issue I am having is trying to display a video in the application's folder.  The HTML I am writing is below

```
<video controls style='width: 200px;height: 151px;'>
    <source src='C:\Users\SomeUser\MyAppFolder\Media\media.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <object data='C:\Users\SomeUser\MyAppFolder\Media\media.mp4'>
        <embed src='C:\Users\SomeUser\MyAppFolder\Media\media.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </object>
</video>
```

This WinForm is using .NET 4.0 and needs to be compatible with WinXp.  I can see that the HTML would fall to the `embed` tag.  If I put an html page in the app folder and open it with IE using only

```
<embed src='C:\Users\SomeUser\MyAppFolder\Media\media.mp4'>
```

I get the ActiveX warning `Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls` and there is a button to allow blocked content, which I am guessing is the problem within the control.  Is it possible to work around this?

Comment: What ActiveX warning?  The one that warns the user that you want to run executable code in their browser?  AFAIK there's no way to work around that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have updated the post with the error.

Comment: It's a feature, not a problem.  You might be able to work around it by having the user turn off the security feature in their browser, but that's not a very good idea.

Comment: I figured that, but I also hoped there would be a way to designate content displayed within my app as trusted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2476360

Comment: With ScriptErrorsSuppressed set to True or False it still doesn't show the button to "allow blocked content".  And my issue isn't with errors, its that it doesn't display anything but an empty media player