# How to display google earth/google map in c# desktop application without using API

Tags: c#, google-maps, webbrowser-control, desktop-application, google-earth

I need help regarding c# desktop application . How to display google earth in webbrowser control in c# desktop application( Lat and long pick from datagridview) without using api.

Comment: Use the same URL you  would in a browser.  Do it manually first.  Then use following in c# : webBrowser1.Navigate("url");

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite: `CefSharp.WinForms` via Nuget, reference [Cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). Note there are some limitations when using the default webBrowser control that's why I used **Cefsharp** for this. You can read this article [C# webBrowser script error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350853/c-sharp-webbrowser-script-error).

Article about [Fun stuff to do with the new Google Earth URL](https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2017/04/fun-stuff-new-google-earth-url.html).

```
private const string googleEarthUrl = "https://earth.google.com/web/@{0},{1},{2}a,{3}d";
private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
private decimal locationAltitude = 200;
private decimal distanceOfEyeFromThePoint = 500000;
```

Initialize

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(getLocationUrl());
gbGoogleEarth.Controls.Add(browser);
```

Get Location URL

```
private string getLocationUrl()
{
    return string.Format(googleEarthUrl, txtLatitude.Text, txtLongitude.Text, distanceOfEyeFromThePoint, locationAltitude);
}
```

Submit

```
browser.Load(getLocationUrl());
```

Sample Output:
[image]