# Script Errors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm currently operating Visual Studio 2012. I have a "URL Scanner" form where once a url is entered into a text box, four web browsers opens up and inputs the url into the site and displays.

My problem is this, I get multiple script error pop ups with a error box that states

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'".

I tried looking up related resolutions but can't get it to work. I'm quite new to VB and hope someone could correct my mistake.

```
Class MainWindow 

Dim WithEvents ScriptWindow As WebBrowser



Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Enter1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a target URL in the space provided!")

    Else
        'Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim theDate As Date
        theDate = Format(Now(), "short date")
        Textboxdate.Text = theDate


        ' file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("URLlogs.txt", True)
        'file.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & " | Date of search: " & Textboxdate.Text)
        'file.Close()

        Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\URLlogs.txt"
        Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path, True)
        writer.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & " | Date of search: " & Textboxdate.Text)
        writer.Close()



        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=" & TextBox1.Text)
        WebBrowser2.Navigate("https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=" & TextBox1.Text)
        WebBrowser3.Navigate("https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/" & TextBox1.Text)
        WebBrowser4.Navigate("https://quttera.com/detailed_report/" & TextBox1.Text)

    End If




End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Reset.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

 End Sub









Private Sub SuppressScriptErrors()
    If (WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
        ScriptWindow = WebBrowser1.Document.Window
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SuppressScriptErrors2()
    If (WebBrowser2.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
        ScriptWindow = WebBrowser2.Document.Window
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SuppressScriptErrors3()
    If (WebBrowser3.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
        ScriptWindow = WebBrowser3.Document.Window
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SuppressScriptErrors4()
    If (WebBrowser4.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
        ScriptWindow = WebBrowser4.Document.Window
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Startpage1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Startpage1.Click
    Me.Hide()

    Dim startwindow As New StartWindow
    startwindow.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub SearchHistory1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles SearchHistory1.Click

    Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\URLlogs.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(path) = True Then
        Process.Start(path)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please generate a search before proceeding")
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is this WPF?  Error looks like it's coming from a remote website, not your code.  Which line throws the error?

Comment: Hi LarsTech, yes this is WPF. Also, it's not a specific line that throws the error. This is a script box from the websites that asks for you to click Yes or No to "Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?" popup.

Comment: Sounds like the error is not in your control.  See [Disable JavaScript error in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2476360/719186)

Comment: Tried their code in my VB but doesn't seem to be compatible sadly.