# Using WebBrowser in a console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I want to use it to invoke some JS scripts on the webpage. I have this:

```
    static void Stuff()
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.iana.org/domains/example/");
        HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
        //doc.InvokeScript("someScript");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        var t = new Thread(Stuff);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

Question 1: I get an "object reference not set" exception when I try to get `doc.ToString()`. Why?

Question 2: How do I get some data from the HTML document into the main program? `WebBrowser` requires a separate thread, which requires a static method which can't return any value. How do I return, say, `doc` to the `Main()` so I can do something with it?

Comment: Static methods actually can return a value. It's threads that can't. Also, threads *can* use a non-static method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right idea, wrong execution.  The WebBrowser.Navigate() only tells the web browser to *start* navigating to the web page you asked for.  That takes time, hundreds of milliseconds typically.  Internet Explorer internally starts threads to get the job done.  It tells you when it is done by raising the DocumentCompleted event.  You don't wait for that so that's crash city first.

Next problem is that the DocumentCompleted event won't be raised in your code.  You have to honor the STA contract, it requires you to pump a message loop.  That's the all-mighty way that a background thread, like the one that IE uses to retrieve a web page, tells *your* thread that the job is done.

The boilerplate code you need is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/c-webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581).

Comment: How would you go about chaining activities? You want to navigate to some page, then enter some text in a text box, and click search, or go. Do you need to just make the WebBrowser object global, and then chain together 4 methods, navigate, navigate's document completed, enter text and hit go, entertextandhitgo's document completed event?

Comment: A state machine is the simple solution to asynchronous programming problems.  Just keep track of the state with an integer or an enum.

Comment: Just a side-note: when trying to automate a WebBrowser control with no user interaction, you will run into serious issues with popup-dialogs unless you set `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` *(which, despite its name, suppresses all dialogs, not just script errors)*. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20612526/238419).