# c# download html string after page loading is finished

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to use a loop to download a bunch of html pages and scrap inside data. But those pages have some javascript job runing when loading. So I am thinking using webclient may not be a good choice. But if I use webBrowser like below. it return empty html string after first call in the loop.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); Thread.Sleep(1000); }
        html = wb.Document.DomDocument.ToString();
```

Comment: What if using the WebClient downloadstring method? does it help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are correct that WebClient & all of the other HTTP client interfaces will completely ignore JavaScript; none of them are Browsers after all.

You want:

```
var html = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
```

Note that if you load via a WebBrowser you don't need to scrape the raw markup; you can use DOM methods like `GetElementById/TagName` and so on.

The while loop is very VBScript, there is a `DocumentCompleted` event you should wire your code into.

---

```
private void Whatever()
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.DocumentCompleted += Wb_DocumentCompleted;

    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com");
}

private void Wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;

    var html = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
    var domd = wb.Document.GetElementById("copyright").InnerText;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. This is the exact answer I am looking for. Could you show me how to add DocumentCompleted event please.

Comment: Edited with example.

Comment: Alex. Thanks. This is console application. I use this code but didn't trigger 
Wb_DocumentCompleted function.

Comment: Oh. See the threading comments:  [Using WebBrowser in a console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324810/using-webbrowser-in-a-console-application)

Comment: Alex. Thanks a million. You saved my day.

Comment: I get ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.'
error. Can you help please?