# c# get content loaded by js from url

Tags: c#, html, download, webclient

I wanna get table from this [url](https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies)
but content loads by javascript.
I download HTML string like this

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var html = wc.DownloadString("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies");
```

how can i get javascript loaded content??

Comment: Do you mean to wait till javascript run and generate the table then you read it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# download html string after page loading is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365068/c-sharp-download-html-string-after-page-loading-is-finished)

Comment: @AmrElgarhy not exactly but that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient and DownloadString will just download the content of the page as string, to be able to run the JavaScript code on this page, you will need an object which understand DOM and can run JavaScript, this will be a browser.

Some more information about this subject:
[Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack)
[Load a DOM and Execute javascript, server side, with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886161/load-a-dom-and-execute-javascript-server-side-with-net/10886733#10886733)