# Problem scrapping dynamically rendered page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-scraping

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I am trying to scrap html of a URL like: "https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-10658066" to get all price and color combinations. The code I am using right now is:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(producturl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    else
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();
}
            
return result;
```

The problem is, the result is not what I want since contains no price which might be because the page is rendered dynamically. Can anyone help me get the whole HTML of the URL?

Comment: The way you are scaping right now, you are making **ONE** request that loads the page, i.e. the HTML code. Interactive elements of this page are **not** triggered by your single request.  There is no easy way to get dynamic data like that. 
You need a headless browser like puppeteer, selenium or phantomjs to *interact* with the dynamic page data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365068/c-sharp-download-html-string-after-page-loading-is-finished Hope this helps...

Comment: Is that for MVC Bhuvaneshwaran?