# C# communicate with Website from console?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, web

is it possible to write some application in C#, which can actually do stuff on a website? something like, go to the website google, type a string in the search box and click on "search"-Button. Or log in into Gmail Account. But all in console.

- cheers

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and depending on what you're dealing with (old style applications vs javascript web applications which make use of ajax) varies from being simple to complex.

Comment: What would you prefer? For dealing with buttons, and other input forms, javascript would be more effective, right?

Comment: I'm not sure of any specific libraries which achieve this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WebBrowser in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324810/using-webbrowser-in-a-console-application)

Comment: I would suggest reading up on Selenium.

Comment: You might take a look at this question about how to use headless chrome from c#: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45130993/597028