# How to cancel or dispose current navigation at WebBrowser element

Tags: c#, navigation, browser, navigateurl

I am developing a C#, .NET Framework 4.0 application. It visits some pages with an order. Sometimes I have to move to the next page without waiting for the previous one to finish the job. How can I cancel the previous navigation process of the `WebBrowser` element?

`WebBrowser` element uses Internet Explorer. Thank you.

This is how I navigate

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mywebsite.com/");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WebBrowser.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

There's two immediate ways to do this. First, you could simply make a call somewhere in your code to the WebBrowser's [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop.aspx) method. However, if you are looking for some more fine tuned control, you could wireup to the WebBrowser's [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event, and do something like this:

```
private void OnWebBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    if (somecondition) {
        e.Cancel = true; // Cancels navigation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WebBrowser1.Stop()`
I remember there being something like this. It cancels the current navigation.