# VB Program won't work on Vista

Tags: vb.net, windows-vista

I have made a program in VB which works like a charm on 3 computers running Win 7. But when I try to run it on a PC running Windows Vista Home Premium 64-bit I get this error:

[image: Error msg]

The fact that it works flawlessly in Win 7 makes me think that it probably is some easy fix I can find. Maybe changing compile options or something like that. If anyone knows anything about this, I would really appreciate your help!

I'm using VB 2010 Express, and I'm running the .exe from Desktop

Comment: The error message text show System.Runtime.InteropService.COMException... What COM component are you using? Was it installed correctly? Sounds to me like a DLL isn't registered. Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, ERROR_BUSY.  Comes out of Internet Explorer so start by updating or fixing IE first.

Answer (score 2):

This error is generated by:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate
```

Here's a question very similar to yours, same error while using `WebBrowser.Navigate`:

[How to fix "The requested resource is in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700AA)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190390/the-requested-resource-is-in-use-exception-from-hresult-0x800700aa)

This is definitely a client side error, I can also see that back-window titled "Internet Explorer script error" - Do you have your Vista fully updated?

This error doesn't really deals with the operating system architecture, it normally occurs when IE is doing something else, for example: displaying a `window.alert` message box.

I say post your full code if possible, and also copy the entire message provided in that error window and post that here instead of the screenshot you currently have.

Are you using **Add-in Express** in your application?

If so, try this as a quick test to see if it still generates the error, got it from this [discussion](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=10&TID=6798):

```
private void adxieCommandItem1_OnClick(object sender, object htmlDoc) 
{ 
this.SendMessage(0x400 + 1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); 
} 

private void IEModule_OnSendMessage(AddinExpress.IE.ADXIESendMessageEventArgs e) 
{ 
if (e.Message == 0x400 + 1000) 
{ 
object dummy = Type.Missing; 

try 
{ 
IEApp.Navigate("http://www.add-in-express.com";, ref dummy, ref dummy, ref dummy, ref dummy); 
} 
catch (Exception err) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show(err.Message); 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Do I have Vista fully updated? No I did not and thought about that after posting this and now I got some bluescreen problems. (The graphics card) But I got 2 PCs running Vista so im going to start the other one now and then also post the full log if I get the error. Thanks for your time!